# Как узнать на каком окне фокус?

Tags: c++, winapi

Кликаю в одно из полей Edit, нужно узнать на каком из полей оказался фокус.

```
HWND myFocus;   

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   ~

   //Создание текстовых полей ввода/вывода:
   HWND myEdit1 = CreateWindow("Edit", NULL, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
   30, 30, 60, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, 0);

   ~

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_HOTKEY:
        {
        switch (wParam) 
        {
        case 0: 
        //1. Определить дескриптор поля на котором фокус...
        myFocus = GetForegroundWindow(); 
        //2. ... чтобы взять значение из этого поля. 
        break;
        }
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: `GetFocus` или отслеживать в оконной процедуре оповещение `EN_SETFOCUS`

Comment: `GetFocus` - окно (или елемент окна) клавиатурного фокуса. `GetCapture` - окно (или елемент окна) мышиного фокуса. Если активировали с клавиатуры, то клавиатурный фокус  не будет совпадать с мышиным (кроме случая если мышиный уже на этом елементе). Если мышкой - будет совпадать.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.